# Creating a list of users who need to update their password

Tags: mysql, sql

I would really appreciate it if y'all could help me solve this problem:
Im trying to figure out a way to determine whether a user needs to update their password. Previously there were no requirements for the strength of one of our users passwords however now my (fake) company is changing that (just self teaching my self for fun). We would like users to include at least 1 symbol, number, and capital letter in their password. We only want a list of user's emails who don't meet those requirements. How can I filter out passwords that meet that requirement? (I honestly don't have a cue where to start)

What I thought about is using ascii numbers to determine whether a password is valid or not and it would be easy for me to do in python or c++ however when it comes to sql, i'm oh so very lost...

### Here is an example of my schema:

```
users
-----------
id
Title
First_Name
Last_Name
Email
Roles
Password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done with the `not like` and checking for the constraints as you can see below. Number, Uppercase, and then a special char

```
select Email from users where
password not like '%[0-9]%' 
and password not like '%[A-Z]%' 
and password not like '%[!@#$%a^&*()-_+=.,;:~]%'
```

As Roshana states, its a good idea to not store any passwords in raw text. That can be a huge security issue.

Comment: @SeamoreBJenkins no prob! Did that work for you? If so mark as answered so people can see what works :)            At some point for sure look up hashing and salting password  happy coding!

Comment: it worked great! :) I think I will use that method and figure out how to encrypt/decrypt the passwords so that I will have a version that can be usable

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a list of such a criteria.

The main reason for that is you **should not store user's raw password**. Without the raw password you cannot apply such filters.

If you really wanna teach yourself, the way to do this is make all of the users update their passwords, then you can add a regex pattern or something to make them do what you want.

---

[image]

This is one of my database examples, as you can see all the passwords are salted and hashed using MD5 hashing mechanism.

Comment: Yea this is a valid point, another good way is to generate a salted and hashed password

Comment: Oh ok yah that make def a good idea. Ill def keep that in mind if I ever choose to implement something like this.

Comment: Oh cool. So lets say I still just wanted to send users who didn't meet the requirements an email. would I just decrypt the hash to determine if they need an update and then get a list of emails from that?

Comment: @SeamoreBJenkins the point is, you can not decrypt MD5. Start a research about hashing mechanisms.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala will do brother